# Julia Function Handle

Tags: function, matlab, julia, function-handle

I want to perform a function_handle in Julia as MATLAB does.
Suppose I create a function in MATLAB like this:

```
fn = @(b, x) process(b, x, @trans);
```

And then I put this function as input of another function `function m = AnotherFunc(m, l, func)` where m is a matrix by:

```
m = AnotherFunc(m, l, fn);
```

And in this AnotherFunc, I should use the function I created as

```
m(a:b,c) = func(m(a:b,c), d);
```

How can I perform this via Julia?

For these 3 I wrote these in Julia:

```
fn = (b,x) -> process(b, x, trans);

m = AnotherFunc(m, l, fn);

m[a:b,c] = func(m[a:b,c], d);
```

Then shows ArgumentError: invalid index: 3.0 of type Float64

I want to write something can perform the same as in MATLAB.

Comment: The issue is probably with some variable of a b c d being a floating point number instead of integer. The function declaration seems correct.

Comment: Please post a [mre] of your Julia code, and copy-paste the full error message. The error is likely in a different place than you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn(b,x) = process(b,x,trans);
AnotherFun(m,l,fn) = begin
  m[a:b,c] = fn(m[a:b,c], d);
  return m
end
```

Note: you did not provide a minimal working example. The variable `l` seems unused and it is not clear where the variables `trans, a,b,c,d` are set.